# python module cannot be found when called from command line

Tags: python

I just started learning Python.

In c:\Python27 I have created my first hello.py script.

It works when I type in the command line:

```
c:\Python27 python hello.py
```

Now I created another script, but in a different directory. This directory is in the 
PYTHONPATH.

```
mymodule.py:
  print("general")

  def fone():    
    print("special line")
```

When I extend the hello.py script:

```
import mymodule

print "Hello"
mymodule.fone()
```

The mymodule script/module gets found and is correctly imported, so the PYTHONPATH seems to be ok.

But when I type at the command line:

```
c:\Python python mymodule.py
```

I get the error:

```
python: can't open file 'mymodule.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why is this?

Thanks alot for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the full path of the file unless it is in the current working directory.

```
python C:\path\to\mymodule.py
```

or you can use `python -m ...` if the module is in the directory (listed in PYTHONPATH):

```
python -m mymodule
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `python mymodule.py`, it looks for `mymodule.py` in the current directory. You need to specify the full path.